# How to use checkbox to change MySQL query?

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

I cannot find any answers on the following issue.
On my website I would like to have a chackbox with `id="filter"`.
The checkbox is needed to allow users choose between "moderated" and "all other" content e.g. if checkbox is checked show "moderated" content, if checkbox is un-checked show "all other content" .

I have 2 different mySQL queries for conntents:

**Moderated Content**

```
$moderated_content = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE showing=1");
```

**All Other Content**

```
$allOther_content = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM articles");
```

Therefore I would like to use these different queries depending on a state of checkbox. I have a cookie that remembers if user has checked or un-checked a checkbox. And I can show different content when they visit the website.

And here is the problem. Say user is already on the webpage and his/her checkbox is unchecked, so they than decide to check a checkbox. How can I show new content after they checked it? I'd like to use AJAX, but I'm not good with it, so the best solution for me would be a page refresh I guess.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can check the value for checked like for example ,

```
if($_POST['filter'] == 1){ 
  // checked
    $moderated_content = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE showing=1");
 }else{
 //not checked
}
```

and you would check if its isset so you dont get any notices

Answer (score 0):

Javascript/jQuery

```
$('#filter').click(function() { 
   document.cookie = "your_cookie="+($(this).attr("checked") ? "1" : "0")+"; path=/";
   window.location.reload();
});
```

PHP:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM articles WHERE ".(empty($_COOKIE['your_cookie']) ? "showing=1" : "1");
```

Comment: Hi @Peter Szymkowski could you please explain jQuery part?